# Hide a line from a table with td class

Tags: html, hide

I'm creating dynamicly an html table with a php code.
If the data are not updated(by date-time check) i get an .offline td class on the created table.

I want to have only the top 5 results sorted by the highest of the 30 temperatures for example.
I'm using

```
table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(n + 6) {
            visibility: hidden;
            }
```

To do that.

But if on the top 5 results is something thats 2 hours old data i want to hide it and displat the next one.

I'm trying with:

```
.offline  {
            display: none;
            }
```

But it just delete the line and i have for example 4 results

This is the complete table style:

```
<html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">

                    <script src="https://cretaweather.gr/protected/sorttabletemp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <link href="../assets/css/templatetable2.css?v=1.1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
                    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        (document.getElementsByTagName( "th" )[1]).click();
    };
</script>
<style>table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {
            background: #c2cdd6;
            }
        table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td {
            background: #ccfffff;
            }
        table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(n + 6) {
            visibility: hidden;
            }
        table.sortable tbody td:nth-child(n + 3) {
            display: none;
            }
        .offline  {
            display: none;
            }
</style>


                </head>
                <body>

                <table align="center" id="template" border="1" bordercolordark="#333333" bordercolorlight="#333333" width="300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; text-align:center;" class="sortable">

                <thead>
                        <tr height="31" bgcolor="#c9e5f2">
                            <th class="sorttable_nosort" width="150" valign="top" align="center">Περιοχή</th>
                            <th class="sorttable_numeric" valign="top" align="center">Θερμοκρασία</th>
                        </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
```

This is a part of created html:

```
</tr><tr class="odd-line">
                    <td class="offline"><a href="http://..." target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#004774;">Μάλια</a></td>
                    <td class="offline">22.3&degC at 8:57</td>
                    <td class="offline">29/04/18</td>
                    <td class="offline">9:01</td>
            </tr><tr class="even-line">
                    <td class=""><a href="http://..." target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#004774;">Μεσοχωριό</a></td>
                    <td class="">25.8&degC at 14:10</td>
                    <td class="">25/05/18</td>
                    <td class="">18:33</td>
            </tr><tr class="odd-line">
                    <td class="offline"><a href="http://..." target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#004774;">Μεταξοχώρι</a></td>
                    <td class="offline">32.3&degC at 13:43</td>
                    <td class="offline">23/05/18</td>
                    <td class="offline">14:00</td>
            </tr><tr class="even-line">
                    <td class=""><a href="..." target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#004774;">Μοχός</a></td>
                    <td class="">22.2&degC at 16:01</td>
                    <td class="">25/05/18</td>
                    <td class="">18:34</td>
            </tr><tr class="odd-line">
                    <td class=""><a href="..." target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#004774;">Πετροκεφάλι</a></td>
                    <td class="">29.4&degC at 13:26</td>
                    <td class="">25/05/18</td>
                    <td class="">18:30</td>
            </tr><tr class="even-line">
                    <td class=""><a href="..." target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#004774;">Πεζά</a></td>
                    <td class="">24.1&degC at 13:26</td>
                    <td class="">25/05/18</td>
                    <td class="">18:30</td>
            </tr><tr class="odd-line">
                    <td class=""><a href="..." target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#004774;">Προφήτης Ηλίας</a></td>
                    <td class="">25.5&degC at 15:16</td>
                    <td class="">25/05/18</td>
                    <td class="">18:34</td>
```

What shall i do to achive that.
visibility: hidden just gives an emty space.

This is how it is displayed now:
[i want to hide the red line thats outdated and display the sixth line instead, to have top5 updated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sB8H.jpg)

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: I would prefer to avoid it. But any solution would be checked.

Comment: Your table is invalid - you have 2 cells in the head and 4 in the body

Comment: I have 2 cell in the head because i want only this 2 to display. The other two are for the date and the time to check if they are recent. I do not want them displayed.